# Python Inheritance Performance Cost

Tags: python, performance

I have multiple inheritance layers and I am trying to understand if this could not lead to a performance issue due to the multiple calls. Here is also a small example to illustrate it:

```
class MySuperClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1


class MyFirstSubClass(MySuperClass):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(arg1)
        self.arg2 = arg2

class MySecondSubClass(MyFirstSubClass):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        super().__init__(arg1, arg2)
        self.arg3 = arg3
```

How does Python work here. Are the super calls executed every time the objects are created?

Comment: How many times are you creating these objects? I doubt the performance of inheritance will be your bottlekneck

Comment: I use these objects as events that are generated frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `super()` is called.

```
%%timeit
x = MySecondSubClass(0, 1, 2)
9.97 µs ± 484 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

vs:

```
class NoInheritance:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3
```

Time:

```
%%timeit
x = NoInheritance(0, 1, 2)
4.31 µs ± 333 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

And using slots:

```
class NoIneritance:
    __slots__ = ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

%%timeit
x = NoIneritance(0, 1, 2)
2.56 µs ± 152 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

And if you don't need any methods on your class, you can use a named tuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
no_inheritance = namedtuple("no_inheritance", ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"])

%%timeit
x = no_inheritance(0, 1, 2)
1.11 µs ± 8.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: @Marvelous Added a named tuple example

Comment: I wonder if slotted dataclasses perform to the same level as the namedtuple.